# genshi and javascript ampersand?

Tags: javascript, genshi

I have the following javascript in my genshi template and I'm unsure how to get it to parse without errors:

```
floor = (!floor && floor !== 0)? 20 : floor;
```

I tried this:

```
floor = (!floor &amp&amp floor !== 0)? 20 : floor;
```

but it always produces this error:

> 'genshi.template.base.TemplateSyntaxError'> at not well-formed (invalid token)

any thoughts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The trick was to wrap the JS code in CDATA tags to hide the js from genshi but ALSO comment the cdata tags out for javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    floor = (!floor && floor !== 0)? 20 : floor;
    // ]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the semicolons.

Does this work?

`&amp;&amp;`

If not, you could just cheat and rewrite it to not use ampersands.

```
floor = floor === 0 ? 0 : floor || 20;
```

Comment: the &amp;$amp; doesn't work because it ends up as that in the final generated javascript

Comment: No, I don't know what to do about less-than :(

Comment: Is genshi xml-based? If so you could try to use a cdata section... just google "cdata section".

Comment: I tried that however the cdata caused the javascript to be ignored by the browser as well.